# ejabberd command creation (find only 1 XMPP)

Tags: ejabberd

I need some help with ejabberd's `ejabberdctl process_rosteritems` command.
I want to search all members of the "xmpp.com" jabber server in roster.
That in users roster is ONLY "xmpp.com", but no other xmpp-servers.

The command

```
ejabberdctl process_rosteritems delete any any any *@xmpp.com
```

is searching not only `xmpp.com`, but also other servers.
So I need some help to create the correct command.

Comment: Can you share your existing command which returns other servers?

Comment: ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any any *@xmpp.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't understand correctly your problem.

Let's imagine user1@localhost, that has two local contacts, also two contacts from xmpp.com, and another two contacts from other host. We can see them all this way:

```
$ ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any *@* *@*
...
user1@localhost user2@localhost
user1@localhost user3@localhost
user1@localhost contact4@xmpp.com
user1@localhost contact5@xmpp.com
user1@localhost contact6@other.com
user1@localhost contact7@other.com
user2@localhost ...
user2@localhost ...
...
```

Then, if I want only to list (or delete) the contacts of user1@localhost that are from xmpp.com:

```
$ ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any user1@localhost *@xmpp.com
...
user1@localhost contact4@xmpp.com
user1@localhost contact5@xmpp.com
```

Can you please edit your question with more details, and maybe some example of what you have, and what you want?

Comment: hi! I want to find xmpp spammers and spam bots. They add only 1 server. So my is localhost. And I want to find xmpp.com. With no other, only xmpp.com. If I do in such way ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any user1@localhost xmpp.com, I will find users with xmpp.com, jabber.org, jabber.no and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this server as example:

```
$ ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any *@localhost *@* | grep -v There | grep -v Progress | grep -v Matches | sort
user1@localhost user2@localhost
user1@localhost user4@xmpp.com
user1@localhost user6@other.com
user2@localhost user3@xmpp.com
user3@localhost user66@xmpp.com
user3@localhost user77@xmpp.com
user4@localhost user99@other.com
```

You want to get the list of users that have as contacts only xmpp.com? In this case it would be user2@localhost and user3@localhost, right? You can do that:

```
$ ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any *@localhost *@xmpp.com | grep -v There | grep -v Progress | grep -v Matches | sort | awk '{print $1}' | uniq >haveyes.txt

$ ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any *@localhost *@* | grep -v There | grep -v Progress | grep -v Matches | sort | grep -v "@xmpp.com" | awk '{print $1}' | uniq >havenot.txt

$ comm -23 haveyes.txt havenot.txt 
user2@localhost
user3@localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're cool ^) It's perfect desicion! And how can I modify grep command, to find all this, but with 2 servers in roster? Like xmpp.com and xmpp.org?

Comment: Users that have at least a contact different than xmpp.com and xmpp.org, try:

ejabberdctl process_rosteritems list any any *@localhost *@* | grep -v There | grep -v Progress | grep -v Matches | sort | grep -v "@xmpp.com" | grep -v "@xmpp.org" | awk '{print $1}' | uniq > havenot.txt